# Changes not applied on production

Tags: python, django, debian, uwsgi

I have server with Nginx + uWsgi(working as emperor). I changed urls.py in one of Django project, but nothing update on production.

I tryed to touch ini file in turned on master(emperor also have master true option), but nothing happened. Emperor logs display that vassal reload:

```
[emperor] reload the uwsgi instance vassal.ini
```

But I didn't see that something update. Is it possible that I need to check something else?

Comment: Where do you host, how do you deploy?

Comment: @BojanKogoj those changes was deployed by editing py file through ssh connection(Putty)

Comment: Did you reload uwsgi?

Comment: @BojanKogoj if you mean /etc/init.d/uwsgi reload - yes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found solution. Vassals didn't reload, but I try to reload emperor and it's work!
In my case it was:

```
/etc/init.d/uwsgi-emperor reload
```